# fishpig wordpress magento integration getPostCollection returns false

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, integration, fishpig

installed fishpig wordpress magento integration and opened sample page (`http://www.example.com/blog/sample-page/`) and it worked successfully except the blog home (`http://www.example.com/blog/`).

I checked the code in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wordpress/post/associated.phtml and found that the code `$this->getPostCollection()` returns false.

Comment: have you resolved errors under magento config, related to url,path,htacces or wordpress theme?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has absolutely nothing to do with the associations system or the template you have referenced. The most likely issue is that another module is loading on /blog/. For example, do you have a CMS page setup that has the URL key of 'blog' and is disabled? Alternatively, do you have a disabled Category setup with the URL key of 'blog'. If either is true, delete the page/category and it will work.

If that isn't the case, check whether you have the AW_Blog module (or another _Blog module). These modules set 'blog' as their frontName in config.xml. This means that Magento passes all requests to this module if the URL starts with blog/, even if the module is disabled in the configuration. Disabling this module properly (in the app/etc/modules/AW_Blog.xml file) will fix the issue.

If AW are listening, you should set your frontName as something unique (eg. aw_blog) and then route requests for /blog/ dynamically. This would allow both my module and yours to work together!